# Complete metric spaces: proving some function is continuous

Tags: general-topology

This is an exercise problem 8 of section 43 from Topology by Munkres.

If $X$ and $Y$ are spaces, define
\begin{equation*}
e:X\times\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\to Y
\end{equation*}
by the equation $e(x, f)=f(x)$; the map $e$ is called the evaluation map. Show that if $d$ is a metric for $Y$ and $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$ has the corresponding uniform topology, then $e$ is continuous.

Here $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ denotes the subset of $Y^X$ consisting of all continuous functions $f:X\to Y$.

To prove the statement, I was thinking using the uniform limit theorem. So I tried to construct $(e_n)$ such that $(e_n)$ converges uniformly to $e$. Then we can conclude $e$ is continuous by the uniform theorem. Am I on the right path? If so, how can I construct such $(e_n)$?

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space? Or just a topological space?

Comment: @popoolmica In this exercise, it just mentions $X$ is a space, so I think we cannot guarantee it is a neither topological space nor metric space. Oh.. then I realize that I cannot use uniform limit theorem..

Comment: The question literally doesn't make sense if $X$ is not a topological space (you need a topology on $X\times \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$). The "uniform topology" is probably the Compact-Open Topology.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou No, the exercise assumes $Y$ is metric $(Y,d)$ and $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has the uniform metric w.r.t $d$.

Comment: Okay... but that's not a metric unless $Y$ is assumed to be bounded? And we still need some sort of topology on $X$.

Comment: I checked the book, it really seems like it says, as in the question here, just "spaces"

Comment: In a topology book, I think it's fairly safe to assume that spaces means topological spaces.

Comment: @popoolmica it shows "show that if $d$ is a metric for $Y$ and " etc. in the question statement. So those *are* the assumptions to use. $e$ can be defined for *all* spaces, so he mentions it as late as possible.

Comment: Yeah, but then what is $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ if $X$ has no structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have on $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ the metric $\overline{d}(f,g)=\sup \{ \min(d(f(x),g(x)),1): x \in X\}$.

To consider continuity at the point $(p,f_0)$, we consider an $\varepsilon>0$ ball around $e(p,f_0)=f_0(p)$. We can assume WLOG that $\varepsilon<1$.

Firstly, $f_0$ is continuous at $p$ so we find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ in $S$ such that $f[U]\subseteq B(f(p_0), \frac{\varepsilon}{3})$.

Now if $x \in U$ and $g \in B_{\overline{d}}(f_0,{\varepsilon \over 3})$, we know
that $$d(g(x), f_0(p)) \le d(g(x), f_0(x)) + d(f_0(x), f_0(p)) \le \overline{d}(f_0,g) + {\varepsilon \over 3} < \varepsilon$$

so that indeed $$e[U \times  B_{\overline{d}}(f_0,{\varepsilon \over 3})] \subseteq B(e(p_0,f), {\varepsilon})$$

showing continuity at the point (as we have a basic open neighbourhood of $(p,f_0)$ mapping inside the open ball around the image).

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$, $x$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. The continuity of $f$ grants the existence of a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that satisfies $f(U)\subset B(f(x),\epsilon/2)$. Then 
$$e(U\times\{g:\|f-g\|_\infty < \epsilon/2\})\subset B(f(x),\epsilon)=B(e(x,f),\epsilon).$$